# How to execute bash aliases functions in the terminal?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, functions

I found out that many people have something like in their `/etc/bash.bashrc` as aliases:

```
del_recursive() {
    find . | grep '$1' | xargs rm
}

process() {
    ps -ef | grep $1
}

apache() {
    sudo service apache2 $1
}

function extract()    # Handy Extract Program.
{
     if [ -f $1 ] ; then
         case $1 in
             *.tar.bz2)   tar xvjf $1     ;;
             *.tar.gz)    tar xvzf $1     ;;
             *.bz2)       bunzip2 $1      ;;
             *.rar)       unrar x $1      ;;
             *.gz)        gunzip $1       ;;
             *.tar)       tar xvf $1      ;;
             *.tbz2)      tar xvjf $1     ;;
             *.tgz)       tar xvzf $1     ;;
             *.zip)       unzip $1        ;;
             *.Z)         uncompress $1   ;;
             *.7z)        7z x $1         ;;
             *)           echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via >extract<" ;;
         esac
     else
         echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
     fi
}
```

but how to execute these in the console? Tried simply to execute as functions, but it just goes to the state where you have to enter some more information. Could somebody point me on how these should be executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `del_recursive` and `extract` expect a filename as first argument:

  ```
  extract foo.tar.gz
  del_recursive bar.txt~
  ```
- `process` looks for patterns in the output of `ps`, you can pass an argument to `grep`, it can be a process name or a PID:

  ```
  process firefox
  ```
- `apache` expects a service command like:

  ```
  apache restart
  ```

Comment: Oh my, thats neat!